# How to pass arguments from :command to function?

Tags: vim

I want to write a command, this command would have this format:

```
[range]MyCMD[!] [count] [oneArg] [flags]
```

or

```
[range]MyCMD[!] [oneArg] [count] [flags]
```

similiar to

```
:[range]P[rint] [count] [flags]
```

or

```
:[range]d[elete] [x] {count}
```

The command `MyCMD` eventually will call a function to do some work. I wrote this line (**won't work**)

```
command! -nargs=+ -range -bang -count=0  MyCMD <line1>,<line2>call MyFUNC(<q-args>, "<bang>","<count>", .... ..)
```

Here the problem is, how to handle those arguments:

- **problem 1** I read about the help, `-range` and `-count` cannot not be used at same time, but I need them both. I also took a look some vim commands, like :delete, :print, when we use those commands, we could give both `range` and `count`. Also I found that vim doc has two entries of same command if a `{count}` or `[count]` is available. like:

  ```
  :[range]d[elete] [x]    
  :[range]d[elete] [x] {count}
  ```

  or

  ```
  :[range]p[rint] [flags]
  :[range]p[rint] {count} [flags]
  ```

  why is that? why not just with `[count]` ? (this would be **another small question**)
- **problem 2** from my design, all those arguments are optional, they have default values(see the table below). How can I pass those arguments to function (I checked `<q-args> and <f-args>`) and how can I distinguish which user-inputs are for which argument? for example user gives

  `:MyCMD 5 g`

  - 5 is count? or arg?
  - g is arg or flag?
  - or '5 g' is arg?

  here is the default values for args:

  ```
  argName | Default value | description
  -------------------------------------
  range   | current line  | this could be get by function xxx ( ) range
  count   | 0             | this could be get by <count>
  bang    | ""            | this is easy too, with <bang>
  arg     | " "           | this argument could have space
  flags   | ""            | no space allowed for flags
  -------------------------------------
  ```

thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your complex custom command, you cannot rely solely on Vim's limited parsing options; you can have it handle the range with `-range`, but have to parse your combination of arguments yourself.

```
:command! -nargs=* -range -bang MyCMD <line1>,<line2>call MyFUNC(<bang>0, <q-args>)
```

Inside `MyFUNC` (which should probably be defined with `:function MyFUNC( ... ) range` to be invoked only once), `split()` the arguments on whitespace. Alternatively, you could define the function to use a variable number of arguments and use `<f-args>`, but note that the number of function arguments is limited (to 20 IIRC).

The `<bang>0` is a nice trick to transform the bang into a boolean, which is usually what you need.

Comment: thx Ingo!. yes, I would parse the args in my function, but I don't know the right way. there are 3 args need to be parsed. count, arg and flags. all are optional.  maybe I should define some format, e.g. for "arg", the value must be wrapped by quote, since spaces are allowed... that could be a little bit easier, then check number or flags string..    or break one command into more commands, this would be the last choice I would do. any more suggestions?

Comment: and do you know the reason of that "another small question" in my post? I searched answer for my problem yesterday, and just noticed that. thank you.

Comment: If your arguments are too ambiguous to be parsed, I'd rethink the syntax; maybe enforce more uniformity or give additional hints what type it is with sigils.

Comment: There's a difference in what built-in commands can handle and what is exposed as parsing options for custom `:commands`; you're treading way beyond the usual uses of custom commands, so all the complexity for parsing is on you.

Comment: finally I parsed the arguments in my function...your answer (and comments) didn't solve my problem directly, but gave me useful information .so I accept this as answer. thank you!

Comment: I love the <bang>0 trick! Is that in the help somewhere? It should be, right by the docs for -bang or <bang>!

Answer (score 1):

Have to ask tough questions. I don't really have any solutions but here are my findings.

```
:command! -range -bang -nargs=* MY echo [<bang>0, <line1>, <line2>, <count>, <q-args>]
```

After running the following scenarios:

```
:MY
[0, 3, 3, -1, '']
:MY!
[1, 3, 3, -1, '']
:%MY
[0, 1, 10, 10, '']
:%MY 4
[0, 1, 10, 10, '4']
:MY 4
[0, 3, 3, -1, '4']
:%MY flag
[0, 1, 10, 10, 'flag']
:MY flag
[0, 3, 3, -1, 'flag']
:%MY 4 flag
[0, 1, 10, 10, '4 flag']
```

Now with `-count` instead of `-range`

```
:command! -count -bang -nargs=* MY echo [<bang>0, <line1>, <line2>, <count>, <q-args>]
```

Results:

```
:MY
[0, 3, 1, 0, '']
:MY!
[1, 3, 1, 0, '']
:%MY
[0, 1, 10, 10, '']
:%MY 4
[0, 1, 4, 4, '']
:MY 4
[0, 3, 4, 4, '']
:%MY flag
[0, 1, 10, 10, 'flag']
:MY flag
[0, 3, 1, 0, 'flag']
:%MY 4 flag
[0, 1, 4, 4, 'flag']
```

As you can see it doesn't easy. My suggestion would be to use `-range` with your command. And then parse the `<q-args>` looking for a number via `\d\+`.

Comment: thanks, Peter. looking for `\d+` is not enough, since the `arg` could be any string, including number, spaces.